# magento custom attribute label disappears

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, custom-attribute

I've created a new phtml page to put inside the view page of the product, in this phtml page I called a new custom attribute that I have associated at the product, whit this code (I've the suggestion in this website, and this was working wonderfully!):

```
        <?php $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
        $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        echo $_product->getAttributeText('video'); ?>
```

but now I have made the new magento update and my custom attribute is disappeared, this is strange because I don't work in the base file of Magento but I've created a my theme to work.
It's possible that something is changed in Magento?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please reindex catalog product

Comment: Did you checked if your attribute is still there and is in the right attribute set?

Comment: Yes, I've check and yes, I don't have touched nothing, the parameter are setting well.
How can I reindex the catalog product? I'm sorry, I start to Magento not a lot time ago.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); 
$_product = $this->getProduct(); 

//Display custom attribute. 
//Attribute code = video;

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$attribute = $product->getResource()
         ->getAttribute('video')
         ->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

echo $attribute;
```

From My [blog](http://www.magentodeveloper.ninja/how-to-display-custom-attributes-on-magento/)